# Testing Middleware with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rack, rack-middleware

I've written some Rack-Middleware and now I'm trying to test it with Rspec.  But all Rack-Middleware is instantiated with an 'app' argument, that represents the Rails app itself.  How do you guys mock this up in Rspec?

For example,

```
 describe MyMiddleWare do
    let(:app) { # How do I mock a Rails app object here? }
    subject { MyMiddleWare.new(app: app) }

    it 'should blah blah blah' do
       # a bunch of tests go here
    end
 end
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You just need the world's simplest Rack app:

```
let(:app) { lambda {|env| [200, {'Content-Type' => 'text/plain'}, ['OK']]} }
```

Also, your middleware's constructor should receive an app as its first parameter not a hash so it should read:

```
subject { MyMiddleWare.new(app) }
```

In all likelihood, though, your test is going to need to determine what effect the middleware has had on the request. So you might write a slightly more sophisticated rack app to spy on your middleware.

```
class MockRackApp

  attr_reader :request_body

  def initialize
    @request_headers = {}
  end

  def call(env)
    @env = env
    @request_body = env['rack.input'].read
    [200, {'Content-Type' => 'text/plain'}, ['OK']]
  end

  def [](key)
    @env[key]
  end

end
```

and then you'll probably want to use Rack::MockRequest to actually send the request. Something like:

```
describe MyMiddleWare do

  let(:app) { MockRackApp.new }
  subject { described_class.new(app) }

  context "when called with a POST request" do
    let(:request) { Rack::MockRequest.new(subject) }
    before(:each) do
      request.post("/some/path", input: post_data, 'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'text/plain')
    end

    context "with some particular data" do
      let(:post_data) { "String or IO post data" }

      it "passes the request through unchanged" do
        expect(app['CONTENT_TYPE']).to eq('text/plain')
        expect(app['CONTENT_LENGTH'].to_i).to eq(post_data.length)
        expect(app.request_body).to eq(post_data)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: There is no call to subject here, how does this actually work?

Comment: This is actually not a valid Rack app. The `lambda` would have to take an argument to be a valid Rack app.

Comment: Fixed arity on simple code example - thanks @branch14.

Comment: what is `@request_headers` for?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use request specs simulating an http request (your middleware should be included in rails middleware stack). See more details on rspec request specs [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-14/docs/request-specs/request-spec).

**UPD** I think I've found exactly what you need, with Test::Unit, but it's easy to rewrite for RSpec: [rack-ssl-enforcer](https://github.com/tobmatth/rack-ssl-enforcer/blob/master/test/helper.rb)

Answer (score 0):

I tested mine like so

```
describe Support::CharConverter do

  let(:env_hash) do
    {
      "HTTP_REFERER" => "", 
      "PATH_INFO" => "foo",
      "QUERY_STRING" => "bar",
      "REQUEST_PATH" => "is",
      "REQUEST_URI" => "here",
    }
  end

  subject do 
    Support::CharConverter.new(env_hash)
  end

  context 'sanitize_env' do

    it 'should keep key values the same if nothing to sanitize' do
      sanitized_hash = subject.sanitize_env(env_hash)
      # k = env_hash.keys[5]
      # v = env_hash.values[5]
      env_hash.each do |k, v|
        sanitized_hash[k].encoding.name.should eq("US-ASCII")
        sanitized_hash[k].should eq(v)
        sanitized_hash[k].valid_encoding?.should eq(true)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing a **Sinatra** app with a middleware and I followed @ritchie's path, and ended up creating an app that looks like this:

```
# Return the params in the response body as JSON
class ParamsInResponseApp < Sinatra::Base
  def call(env)
    super

    rack_params = env["rack.request.query_hash"]

    [200, {"Content-Type" => "application/json"}, [{"app" => rack_params}.to_json]]
  end
end
```

Inheriting from `Sinatra::Base` and calling `super` allowed me to get the params from `env["rack.request.query_hash"]`, which was otherwise `nil`.

Note that this app puts the params in the response, so I can check them without having to stub anything.